# RewriteRule works in .htaccess not in another included file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a server with Magento and Wordpress.

Magento is in the website root `/`, Wordpress under `/blog/`.

Various `Redirect 301` and `RedirectMatch permanent` are specified in a file in the website root. This file is "included" from the Apache vhost configuration:

```
Include /var/www/html/myredirects
```

Some pages from Wordpress should be visible from the website root, so that

```
http://www.mymagento.com/pretty-url/
```

will show the same content as

```
http://www.mymagento.com/blog/pretty-url/
```

This is currently achieved using in the `.htaccess` file using some rewrites as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^pretty-url/ /blog/pretty-url/ [L]

    [...more like the above here and the common Magento rewrites follow...]

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(html|jpg|png|gif)$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Requested-With} !=XMLHttpRequest
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is it possible to move just the `RewriteRule` lines that show some pages from the blog in the root to the `myredirects` file?

I tried moving them with and without the part

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

and in both cases it does not work, either a blank page or a Server Error is the result.

I cannot find in the Apache documentation what is the reason why whatever is defined in the `.htaccess` makes it work. Maybe it's because of the processing order?

Edit, as asked how `myredirects` looks like (please note these redirects work already):

They are a bunch of URLs with different product categories from Magento plus some related to the `/blog/`, they all look like these:

```
# These are Magento
RedirectMatch permanent /product-category/sub-category-1/sub-category-2/(colorA|colorB|colorC) /sub-category-2/$1
Redirect 301 /someurl/otherurl/ /another/url
# These are for Wordpress
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/some-tag/ /blog/some-tag/
Redirect 301 /blog/tag/another-tag/ /blog/another-tag/
```

Those for the blog are only redirecting the `/tag/` part and nothing else.

And yes, it's only some of the `/blog/` URLs that should be shown also in the website root, others will stay under `/blog/` (I know there will be duplicate content for those shown in both paths).

Comment: What does `myredirects` file look like?

Comment: Yes, show the mydirects, you can't debug apache stuff without seeing what you are actually using. You are not actually putting in the literal urls for each pretty-url just so you can skip the /blog/ part are you? That's a pretty serious error unless it's just for a few pages, you want the rewrite rules to 'just work' as intended, ie, one set for the /blog/ and one for the other. Internal apache rules have slightly different syntax from .htaccess rules, particularly with the paths, htaccess they do not start with /, in the config files, they do. I think. Pick one, htaccess or myredirects.